# Help with using some trig identities

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Need some help with the steps in converting the derivatives of the following functions.

1. derivative of  $\cos(\tan(x))$ to  $\frac{-\sin(\tan (x))}{\cos^2(x)}$

   I can get $-\sec^2(x) \cdot (\sin(\tan(x))$ using chain rule, but then I am stuck.  I guess I just need help on understanding how $\sec^2(x) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$
2. derivative of $\sin(x)\tan(x)$ to $\sin(x) + \tan(x) \cdot \sec(x)$

I can get $\cos(x) \cdot \sec^2(x)$ but then I am unsure what to do.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, remember that $\sec$ is the reciprocal of $\cos$ by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Reciprocal_functions).

For the second, you should use the [product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) to find the derivative, don't simply take the derivative of each factor. Then use the fact that $\tan{x}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos{x}}$ to simplify your expression and get the desired form. Try rewriting every function in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to most easily simplify.

Comment: Thanks, I see using product rule I get sinx(1/cox^2(x)) + (sinx/cosx)(cosx)  which simplifies to sinx + tanxsecx

Comment: @Finzz, exactly, nice job.

Answer (score 3):

1. $\sec(x)$ is defined to be $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, that is the ratio of the length of the hypotenuse and the length of the adjacent side.
2. Note that $\tan(x)\cdot \sec(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x)} =  \sin(x) \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$.